# Cannot join to an invited project in another Azure Devops organization

Tags: azure-devops

- Create an organization and a project using a Microsoft account
- Invite another Microsoft account to the project
- An email goes to the invitee with a link to join the project

When the invitee tries to join, the following error is displayed:

```
401 - Uh-oh, you do not have access.
Your account, <invitee_email_id> is not authorized to view this page.  
Make sure the URL is correct and your account has access.   
View a list of your organizations here.   
You may request access by contacting the admin.
```

What am I missing? I know this question has been asked before but those answers don't help. Also, my scenario is as simple as has been described.

Comment: I am not sure if works but you could add the user on the organization first by navigating on `Organization Settings -> Users -> Add users`

Comment: That's exactly what is done. Also, the user is added to the project.

Comment: Does this user belong in your organization? If not you should enable external guest access https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-external-user?view=azure-devops

Comment: The users are plain Microsoft accounts. Is it that I have to necessarily use Azure AD to achieve what I am trying to? I am asking because I don't see the option in org policies.

Comment: I mean do I have to connect my org to Azure AD?

Comment: Normally by adding users in your organization it should work for any microsoft account. I tried it myself today. When adding new users you could select basic, and then select on which projects you need to provide access. As currently is not working for you I would suggest removing and adding again the user on the organization.

Comment: You are right, it works. I should have paid more attention to the error message. It says "Your account, is not authorized to view this page". The error was about another user who was already logged in. I logged him out using https://aka.ms/vssignout. After that, it worked.